# slideDown drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, slidedown

so I'm trying to make a nice little effect on my drop down menu, but i don't know the right way to use the hover and slideDown function

```
$('nav > div > ul > li').hover(function() {
    $('nav > div > ul > li > ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    $('nav > div > ul > li > ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);

});
```

that is what i have now, this don't work it shows my submenu regardless of what li I'm hovering, i want it to work so it is on the element and only the element that has the submenu.

**EDIT: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MzJNT/)**

Comment: Can you post the markup as well? Even better, can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Hmm, what exactly do you want to accomplish? It's working for me.

Comment: It shows the drop down no matter what li element you mouse over, i only want it to show when you mouse over the parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MzJNT/2/

I would suggest adding some ID for selectors like below

JS 
     $( document ).ready(function() {

```
$('#parent').hover(function() {
    $('#submenu').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    $('#submenu').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);

});

 });
```

I am sure there is a more efficent way to do this but this is a good start.

**EDIT**

I think i found the actual issue with why it isn't sliding like you want it too, you have a style that is making it show instead of using the JS to make it show up

Remove this...

```
     nav > div > ul > li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
     }
```

or try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MzJNT/9/

Comment: Hi travis, this simply does not work smoothly enough. Its like it not using the sliding effect every time, and its only triggered if the menu have been showed and hovered before, but thanks for thanks for the awnser :)

Comment: Then change the duration length to something more than 200 that is SUPER fast but i was using your code try this http://jsfiddle.net/MzJNT/7/

Comment: Hi Travis. First of all thanks for you time, but in your example. If i start by hovering home or li and then the parent no slide function happens.

Comment: OK i think i figured it out check out my edit above you have the stylesheet using display:block which sometimes that fires and sometimes the HS fires giving it that erratic behavior.

Comment: So ended up using classes like you, and the just screw to fallback if user have disabled javascript in the browser

Comment: Nice work! That menu you should look pretty slick when it is done... cheers!